# Return only the categories which have products (Elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I have two indexes Categories and Products. A product has only one category.

I am looking for a way to query **the Category index** and filter out all categories that have no products.

**Product**

- id
- name
- category

  - id
  - name
- price

**Category**

- id
- name

Any ideas on how I can achieve that?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasDilawar I tried to use a `nested` query but I dont think I can do that with it.

Comment: You should add that code to your question as it will help in better understanding the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a `terms` aggregate on field `category.id` in `Product` index. Notice set `size` of the aggregate (NOT the global size to specify the return hits) a big number.

Comment: But I am querying the Category index.. :/

Comment: Follow an ids query I guess